# Ocultar credenciales a desarrolladores

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, seguridad

Quizás la siguiente pregunta sonara algo ilógica, pero ¿existe alguna manera de dar acceso a una base de datos SQL Server sin tener que suministrarle el usuario y la contraseña al desarrollador?

Quisiera que el dominio de ese usuario y esa contraseña sea absolutamente mía. Soy actualmente un DBA, que se preocupa por la seguridad de los datos.

Entiendo que ODBC son inseguros ya que puede ser utilizado por diferentes aplicaciones en la misma computadora, y por otro lado, los connectionstring lo son también ya que para poder construirlos se necesita olbigatoriamente el usuario y la contraseña.

Comment: Hola, te comento que yo tenia el mismo dilema, tuve que crear una base de datos paralela (dev_database) con información que no era relevante, y al momento de generar los backups diferenciales solo actualizo el esquema de esa base de datos, y lo hago con una frecuencia mas baja. Luego yo mismo migro los cambios (stores, ttriggers, y check_clauses) a la bbdd en producción cuando ya están aprobados.

Comment: Has probado mediante autenticación de Windows? Con eso no te preocupas de manejar contraseñas y todo se controla mediante grupos de Active Directory.

Comment: La autenticacion windows no es opcion ya que el tipo de lenguaje utilizado es un poco arcaico y solo acepta conexion con autenticacion SQL. Por otro lado los mismos desarrolladores dan soporte a los usuarios y son quienes compilan para la mayoria de las aplicaciones.

Comment: Buen día, lo mejor que puedes hacer si quieres cuidar la seguridad de tus bases de datos es crear roles específicos, así tu puede asignar como dba que es lo que pueden ver, mover, borrar o consultar, puedes cerrarles el acceso por tabla o por esquema. Aunque lo ideal es que los desarrolladores no tengas acceso al ambiente productivo y que los cambios a esta base los haga ya sea el dba o algún otro puesto que previamente lo haya probado en un ambiente QA o Beta. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una conexión a través de un archivo de configuración cifrado tal como lo usaría una aplicación. De todas maneras limitas el trabajo del desarrollador que tampoco creo que es la idea.

Si realmente te preocupa el acceso a información que pueda ser sensible, lo mejor es dar accesos específicos. Solo cierto tipo de operaciones a ciertos objetos. O también se puede ir por el lado contrario, accesos completos de lectura y escritura denegando  el acceso a objetos que puedan ser críticos.

Finalmente la última opción sería generar ambientes de desarrollo sin información sensible (datos ofuscados o sin datos) y dar libre uso al equipo de desarrolladores

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias. Pero el usuario debe tener privilegios a esos objetos y datos ya que es el usuario que usará la aplicación para trabajar. Por lo que en estos momentos deben de conocerlo para hacer que la aplicación conecte con la base de datos.